# Python warnings - any way to remove the raw warning output at the end of a custom warning message

Tags: python, warnings

I'm trying to create a custom warning message in a Python script:

```
allfiles = glob.glob(folderpath + "\\*.xlsx")
if not allfiles:
    warnings.warn('No xlsx data files are found in the folder "'+folderpath+ '"!\n Please note that currently the program could process only this data format. ')
```

The problem is that during execution of the script, if I trigger this message the output looks like:

```
UserWarning: No xlsx data files are found in the folder "C:\Users\Savina\Desktop\project\"!
 Please note that currently the program could process only this data format. 
  warnings.warn('No xlsx data files are found in the folder "'+filepath+ '"!\n Please note that currently the program could process only this data format. ')
```

I don't want this `warnings.warn...` on the last row to appear and to show the raw structure of the message. Any way to hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this: `warnings.warn('No xlsx data files are fo...' , stacklevel=2)`