# How to suppress the stacklevel in python warnings module

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I do `warnings.warn(...)` I get something like this:

```
as.py:80: UserWarning: Value of 16777215 shortened to 8-bit value of 255
  warnings.warn(f'Value of {self.value} shortened to {size}-bit value of {value}')
```

By default it will print [`stacklevel=1`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn), and I can change the stacklevel to print the parent caller and such. How do I entirely suppress the second line though? So I can just do:

```
warnings.warn('Here is your warning')
```

And it prints:

```
file.py:80: Here is your warning
```

Or is that not really possible and if you just want to print a stack-less warning to do `log.warn(...)` ?

Comment: Completely unrelated: But it seems very suspicuios to completely edit a question beyond recognition, then add a bounty on it less than a minute later.

Comment: **Moderator Note** - Please do not overwrite a particular question that you have asked with a completely different and unrelated question. [Ask a new question instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @David542 what happened is that you appeared to try and work around our requirements for a *delay* between first posting a question and posting a bounty on the question. Please don’t do that. It is not fair to others that do stick to those requirements.

Comment: answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62778015/5885810)?
```warnings.warn('Here is your warning', stacklevel=2)```